# My iPad keeps asking to configure it after sync with iTunes

Tags: ipad, itunes, windows, restore, ipados

- I've saved my iPad 1 config on iTunes
- I've updated iTunes on my PC
- I've updated my iPad from iTunes
- I've restored my config from iTunes

There's a black screen with a white apple, then my iPad shows a screen similar to this:

[image]

I've done this several times (restore from iTunes). Same result.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of approximating, why not send a snap of your iPad's restore screen?  The fact that it's an iPad1 is probably of note.

Comment: at the end, I had to reset my iPad...